# Splitting the string in Java to give the desired output

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String like `"key=value=="`.
I want to split the above to give me the output as

```
key  
value==
```

When i used `("key=value==").split("=")`, it gave me the below

```
key
value
```

I understand why it is giving this(because of `'='` in `value==`).May I know how to correct it? How should i write my Java code so that I can get below as output

```
key  
value==
```

Comment: `substring(0,str.indexOf("="))` and `substring(str.indexOf("="))`

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a limit for the [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) function. The second parameter is the maximum number of elements you want to get. In your case that is 2.

```
("key=value==").split("=",2)
```

Answer (score 1):

After some tries, I got the solution as below

```
("key=value==").split("=",2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression as the split-statement is also possible:

```
("key=value==").split("\\=(?!=)(?!$)");
```

This expression will match any '=' if it is not followed by another '=' or if it is not the last one in the current line.